# Android Studio generated signed apk issue Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to export a signed apk of my exported project from eclispe ADT to Android Studio.

I have 2 issues:

> Error:(16, 0) Gradle DSL method not found:
>   `'lintOptions()'`

Possible causes:

The project 'gigCheck2' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

And when I'm trying to generate the apk:

> Missing Gradle Project Information. Please check if the IDE
>   successfully synchronized its state with the Gradle Project
>   Model.

I've two `build.gradle`
1-Inside root project:

```
<code>// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}</code>
```

2-In the app

```
<code>
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.project.client.android"
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 10
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles 'proguard.cfg'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('lib/commons-codec-1.7.jar')
    compile files('lib/commons-io-2.4.jar')
    compile files('lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar')
    compile files('lib/core.jar')
    compile files('lib/javase.jar')
    compile files('lib/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.0.0.jar')
}

</code>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove **lintOptions** in root level gradle file and add it in app level gradle file.

Your app>build.gradle look like this.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.project.client.android"
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 10
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles 'proguard.cfg'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
      abortOnError false
      checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('lib/commons-codec-1.7.jar')
    compile files('lib/commons-io-2.4.jar')
    compile files('lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar')
    compile files('lib/core.jar')
    compile files('lib/javase.jar')
    compile files('lib/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.0.0.jar')
}
```

Comment: Additionally, it may be good to note that you shouldn't mod the root gradle build file. Android Studios provides warnings about that.

Answer (score 0):

lint options should be included in your module gradle not project:

```
android{
   defaultConfig {
       lintOptions {
           abortOnError false
           checkReleaseBuilds false
      }
   }
}
```